# Constructing a Green function for Sturm - Liouville operator

Tags: greens-function, sturm-liouville

I can't find Green function for the Sturm - Liouville operator :
$$
 L = - \frac{d²}{dx²} + 1
$$

with condition : $v(0) = v(1) = 0$

I would appreciate any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use dollar signs for math formatting. Like this: $L = - \frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2} + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The Green function is the integral kernel of the solution to $Lf=g$, where $f\in\mathcal{D}(L)$ means that $f$ is twice differentiable with $f(0)=f(1)=0$. If $\varphi,\psi$ are solutions of $Lf=0$ with conditions
$$
                 \varphi(0)=0,\;\varphi'(0)=1 \\
                 \psi(1)=0,\;\psi'(1)=1,
$$
then a solution of $Lf=g$ can be constructed using variation of parameters, and found to be
$$ 
        f = \frac{\psi(x)}{w}\int_0^xg(y)\varphi(y)dy+\frac{\varphi(x)}{w}\int_x^1g(y)\psi(y)dt, \\
         \varphi(x)=\sinh(x),\;\; \psi(x)=\sinh(x-1)
$$
where $w=\psi'(x)\varphi(x)-\psi(x)\varphi'(x)$ is the Wronskian. $w$ is a constant in $x$ in this case because
$$
    w'=\psi''\varphi-\psi\varphi''=\psi\varphi-\psi\varphi=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much !